# Fusion tables dynamic maps strokeOpacity

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have tweaked this example for my map:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/dynamic_styling_template

But i want the opacity of the border to be 0 (so nobody sees it). I guess i have to do something in this peace of code with strokeOpacity: 0.0, but I can't get it to work

```
  // Apply the style to the layer & generate corresponding legend
  function applyStyle(map, layer, column) {
    var columnStyle = COLUMN_STYLES[column];
    var styles = [];

    for (var i in columnStyle) {
      var style = columnStyle[i];
      styles.push({
        where: generateWhere(column, style.min, style.max),
        polygonOptions: {
          fillColor: style.color,
          fillOpacity: style.opacity ? style.opacity : 0.8
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [PolygonOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolygonOptions)

This seems to be the best you can do:

```
 strokeOpacity: 0.0001,
 strokeWeight: 0,
 strokeColor: style.color,
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_dynamic_styling_template.html)

UPDATE:
Looks like strokeOpacity: 0.0 doesn't work; try something really small, like 0.0001.

Comment: yes I tried alle three but it didn't work. In your example it nearly works. If i copy your example I notice that it only works completly if you put the fillOpacity at 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set it to 1% ie:

strokeOpacity: 0.01