# google.maps.Polyline - how to get a transparent / invisible polyline?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, colors, transparent, polyline

I have the following code for a route where an animation goes on, so i need the polyline but i don't want to show it:

```
[..]
    this.polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [],
                strokeColor: '#ffffff',
                strokeWeight: 0
            });
[..]
```

The polyline is shown with that code. But i want to make the polyline transparent - not visible! How can i do it?

I set the **strokeColor** to "transparent" - what doesnt work, either not when i remove the option completely. I also set the **strokeWeight** to 0 - but these parameters have no effect. I tried also **strokeOpacity** from 0.0 to 1.0 - also no effect. Knows someone a solution? - PS: when i change the color to #ff0000 the color should be red, right? but it seems to be that the options doesn't work at all - but the polyline is shown and i have no JavaScript errors in the console.log...?

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions) the link to the reference with nearly the same example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlanCoordinates,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.00001,
      strokeWeight: 0
    });
```

For some unknown reason strokeOpacity: 0.0 doesn't work.

[Simple polyline example from the Google Maps API v3 documentation](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_polyline_simple.html)

[same code with a transparent polyline](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_polyline_simple_transparent.html)

[Similar question about transparent polylines on FusionTablesLayers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004656/fusion-tables-dynamic-maps-strokeopacity/14005835#14005835)